# Subprocess.run does not work on Windows with file names containing spaces

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Powershell in Windows 10

```py
>>> import os, subprocess
>>> os.listdir('C:\\Program Files') # works
>>> subprocess.run('ls C:\\') # works
>>> subprocess.run('ls C:\\Program Files') # Fails
```

I have tried forward slashes, escaping, 'r' to make a regex, the string enclosed within quotes, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work in the terminal either. You should quote the file path in the subprocess command:

```
subprocess.run('ls "C:\\Program Files"')
```

Everything in those quotes is then read as a single term.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Interesting that the argument(file name in this case) MUST be wrapped with double quote or it fails if the quotes were "switched around" meaning single inside of double...

Comment: Is that the case? I would expect `subprocess.run("ls 'C:\\Program Files'")` to work as Powershell accepts single quotes. Regardless, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

By passing your command as a single string, you're leaving it to Python to break up the command into arguments. You can either quote the argument that contains spaces as shown by @Kraigolas, or simply break up the command yourself and pass a *list* of the command and its arguments. I favor this approach because it is easy to use with variables without worrying about having to quote them.

```
subprocess.run(["ls", r"C:\Program Files"])
```

Comment: I think one could also use `('ls C:\\Program Files'.split())` as the args.

Comment: No, that won't work, it will make the filename into two args, which is how it's already broken. You could use `shlex.split` though.